# Unable to Trigger Downstream Jenkins Job Based on the Promoted Builds Plugin

Tags: jenkins

I have a request from a user who is currently using the [Promoted Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=77889556) plugin for Jenkins. This user would like Job_B to be triggered when a build from Job_A has been promoted.

In Manage Jenkins > Configure System, there are three "Promotion Levels" defined.

When I navigate to Job_B > Config, check the "Build when another project is promoted", and enter the name of Job_A in the Job Name box. However, the "Promotion" drop-down does not populate with any of the three promotion levels.

[image: Screenshot showing the Build when another project is promoted option]

Job_A is a Freestyle job, while Job_A is a Pipeline. I thought this was the source of the issue, but when creating a test FreeStyle job, I still wasn't able to see anything populate the Promotion drop-down. Any idea what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Job chaining is a CI/CD anti-pattern and one of the big drivers behind developing pipelines. If the next step in the equation is to do more work, just make it a stage in the pipeline. If you need separation for whatever reason, make the freestyle job a pipeline job and add a post->success step.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post